# how array of strings in C looks like in the memory?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how 2d char array looks like in the memory.
for example:

```
    char   c[][5]={"xa","ccc","bb","j","a","d"};

    printf("TEST: %u %u %u %u \n\n",c[0],*c[0],c[0]+1,*(c[0]+1));
```

output:

TEST: 3214246874 120 3214246875 97

c[0]=*(c+0) is the string "xa", and equals to 3214246874, so I guess c[0] is the address to the char array "xa".
when I put a * to c[0], I got 120 which is 'x' in ascii.

so I think the first space in c array is an address to the char x.
after that I tried the same with c[0]+1, and it printed the next address, and then i put * and i got ,97 which is 'a' in ascii.

so I assumed the array c looks like this:

```
c[0]                              c[1]
------------------------------------------------------------------
| pointer to x | pointer to a ||| pointer to c | pointer to c | etc ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but I searched the web and I didnt find any proof for my assumption.

Comment: It will be just a contiguous memory region of size 5*6 containing characters. No pointers are going to be stored there.

Comment: printing a pointer using `%u` invokes UB.

Comment: Eugene Sh. is right, but just take a look at the memory in a debugger, or print it out to console for evidence.

Comment: Don't change the question once you have an answer addressing the changed information! Rolling back.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it doesn't addressing the changed information. pointer is an address as far as I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are conflating two senses of the term "string" as it is used in C.

Most correctly, a C string is a null-terminated *array* of `char`.  You have declared an array of `char` arrays, and initialized it with null-terminated char sequences.  It is perfectly reasonable to characterize this as an "array of strings".

***Arrays are not at all the same thing as pointers***, however.  The elements of your array are other arrays, each one (in your case) five `chars` long.  This is where the other sense of the term "string" comes in.  C arrays are a bit slippery; if you evaluate a (sub-)expression of array type, it evaluates to a pointer to the first array element.  In the case of strings, such a pointer has type `char *`, and so it is common it refer to pointers into strings as strings themselves.  That is a colloquialism, however, and you will get yourself into trouble if you do not recognize the difference between the two related meanings.

Breaking down your example code:

> ```
>     char   c[][5]={"xa","ccc","bb","j","a","d"};
>
>     printf("TEST: %u %u %u %u \n\n",c[0],*c[0],c[0]+1,*(c[0]+1));
> ```

- The expression `c[0]` designates an array of five `char`.  When evaluated in the context of the function call expression, it becomes a pointer to the first element of the array.  This value is of type `char *`, which is not the correct type for the corresponding `printf` field descriptor, `%u`.  Undefined behavior results.  You could correct this by casting the argument to `void *` and changing the field descriptor to `%p`.
- Given that `c[0]` evaluates to a pointer to the first `char` of the first member array, it follows that the expression `*c[0]` evaluates to the pointed-to `char`.  This value again fails to match the corresponding field descriptor, which should be `%c` -- you should then expect 'x' to be printed.  Alternatively, you could cast the value: `(unsigned int)*c[0]`.  In that case, you would expect the numeric code for 'x' to be printed; that is very likely to be 120.  That 120 is in fact the value actually printed is an inconsequential characteristic of the specific manifestation of the undefined behavior of your program.
- Again given that `c[0]` evaluates to a pointer to the first `char` of the first member array, it follows that `c[0] + 1` is a *pointer* addition, resulting in a pointer to the second `char` in that array.  As with `c[0]`, this does not match the format.
- And presumably it will be clear by this point that `*(c[0] + 1)` evaluates to the second `char` (at index 1) in array `c[0]`.  The expression is rigorously equivalent to `c[0][1]`.  This again does not match the format.

> so I assumed the array c looks like this [...]

Nope.  The array looks like this:

```
| c[0]         | c[1]         | c[2]         | c[3]         | c[4]         | c[5]         |
  x  a \0 \0 \0  c  c  c \0 \0  b  b \0 \0 \0  j \0 \0 \0 \0  a \0 \0 \0 \0  d \0 \0 \0 \0
```

Comment: thanks you! so c[0] in the real memory is 'x', but in C it will be evaluate  to the address of the first element of the sub array?

Comment: No, @Daniel2708, the representation of `c[0]` in memory is not (just) 'x'.  `c[0]` is an array of five `char`s, which you have initialized with the specific `char` sequence `xa\0\0\0`.  Those five `char` values *together* are its representation in memory.  But yes, when C evaluates an expression containing or consisting of `c[0]`, which designates an array, that array is replaced by a pointer to its first element for the purpose of evaluating the expression.

Comment: @JohnBollinger *with the specific char sequence xa\0\0\0* - Aren't the last two `\0` are actually "don't-cares"?

Comment: I meant, in the physical memory, c[0] as 1 byte  is 'x' , and not an address? C evaluated it as address in the example . this is what I understood. thank you again :)

Comment: @EugeneSh., definitely not.  This falls under the partial initialization rule in C2011 6.7.9/21: "If there are [...] fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements  in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall  be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."  For elements of type `char`, that means initialization to 0.

Answer (score 2):

`c` looks like this internally:

```
c[0]                   c[1]                  c[2]                  c[3]
|                      |                     |                     |
[0] [1] [2]  [3]  [4]  [0] [1] [2] [3]  [4]  [0] [1] [2]  [3]  [4] 
'x' 'a' '\0' '\0' '\0' 'c' 'c' 'c' '\0' '\0' 'b' 'b' '\0' '\0' '\0' ...
```

I.e. it's one long sequence of chars. It doesn't store any pointers or addresses.

The compiler knows the sizes of each part, so when you write e.g. `c[2][1]`, it knows to fetch it from offset `2 * 5 + 1` = `11` (from the beginning of `c`).

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
char c[][5] = {"xa", "ccc", "bb", "j", "a", "d"};
```

can be written more explicitely as:

```
char c[6][5] = {"xa\0\0\0", "ccc\0\0", "bb\0\0\0", "j\0\0\0\0", "a\0\0\0\0", "d\0\0\0\0"};
```

The `c` is array of `6` elements, where each element is of type `char[5]`. Each "subarray" takes `5` bytes (`char` always takes one byte), and they are placed next to each other. Thus, the total memory space occupied by `c` array is `30` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Beware: arrays of pointers and 2D arrays are different animals! Once defined you use them almost the same way, but they are stored differently in memory.

1. Arrays of pointer:

   ```
   char   *c[]={"xa","ccc","bb","j","a","d"};
   ```

   This defines an array of 6 pointers. Each of this pointers points to its string that will be stored elsewhere in memory. A typical representation will be:

   ```
   c -> address_of_x, address_of_c, address_of_ ... (array of pointers)
   'x', 'a', '\0', 'c', 'c', 'c', '\0', 'b'... (arrays of chars)
    -               -                    -
   ```

   The whole thing will use (in a 32 bits architecture): 6*4 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 40 bytes
2. 2D array:

   ```
   char   c[][5]={"xa","ccc","bb","j","a","d"};
   ```

   This defines a 2D array of 6 rows of 5 columns each (exactly 30 bytes):

   ```
   'x', 'a', '\0', ?, ?, 'c', 'c', 'c', '\0', ?, 'b' ...
   ```

   (bytes noted as ? are *do not care*, they may be initialized or not depending of the implementation and the build options).

But whatever definition you use, `c[1][2]` will be the third character of the second string, and `*(c[0] + 1)` (which is *by definition* the same as `c[0][1]`) is the second char of first string, that is: `x`.